# System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: client-server, azure-service-fabric, grpc-c#

I am trying to run a simple Client Servier Communicaton application on .NET Framework using C# and service fabric.For inter-service communication I am trying to use gRPC and I have made both the Client and Server as separate services on the cluster.I am using reliable service API to override the functions and establish inter-service communication. However when I run the code I get this error:-

```
Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in mscorlib.dll
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in
 'C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\TestGRPC\ClientService\bin\x64\Debug\ClientService.exe'.

Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xeed5af27, on thread 0x578. The error code is 0x80131623.
This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code.
Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

And I figured out the line that was responsible for this error:-

```
static Random mRand = new Random();
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            long iterations = 0;
            ServicePartitionResolver partitionResolver = new ServicePartitionResolver("localhost:19000");
            var partition = partitionResolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/TestGRPC/gRPCServer"),
                ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
            var endpoint = partition.Endpoints.ElementAt(mRand.Next(0, partition.Endpoints.Count));

            var address = endpoint.Address.Substring(endpoint.Address.IndexOf("\"\":\"") + 4);
            address = address.Substring(0, address.IndexOf("\""));

            Channel channel = new Channel(address, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            var client = new AccountService.AccountServiceClient(channel);
            while (true)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                EmployeeName empName = client.GetEmployeeName(new EmployeeNameRequest { EmpId = "1" });
                if (empName == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(empName.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(empName.LastName))
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Emplyee Not found");
                    Console.WriteLine("Employee not found.");
                }
                else
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Emplyee Name: {0} {1}", empName.FirstName, empName.LastName);
                    Console.WriteLine($"The employee name is {empName.FirstName} {empName.LastName}.");
                }
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

is the line

```
EmployeeName empName = client.GetEmployeeName(new EmployeeNameRequest { EmpId = "1" });
```

I suspect that somehow the domain name is not being resolved properly or I am unaware of how to generate the correct domain name address .The same is indicated in the warning message. The server seems to run fine on the cluster.
The warning message as well as the stack trace displayed on the cluster is:-

```
'RunAsync' reported Warning for property 'RunAsyncUnhandledException'.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="DNS resolution failed for service: MININT-H7Q1KHO:50001", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1624221009.546000000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":1361,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624221009.546000000","description":"DNS resolution failed for service: MININT-H7Q1KHO:50001","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":362,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624221009.545000000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=MININT-H7Q1KHO is_balancer=0: Domain name not found","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":724,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624221009.545000000","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=AAAA name=MININT-H7Q1KHO is_balancer=0: Domain name not found","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolver\dns\c_ares\grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":724}]}]}]}")
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/AsyncCall.cs:line 78
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/DefaultCallInvoker.cs:line 46
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/Interceptors/InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:line 51
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/ClientBase.cs:line 174
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in /var/local/git/grpc/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/Interceptors/InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:line 48
   at AccountService.AccountServiceClient.GetEmployeeName(EmployeeNameRequest request, CallOptions options) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\TestGRPC\ClientService\AccountGrpc.cs:line 100
   at AccountService.AccountServiceClient.GetEmployeeName(EmployeeNameRequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\TestGRPC\ClientService\AccountGrpc.cs:line 96
   at ClientService.ClientService.<RunAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\TestGRPC\ClientService\ClientService.cs:line 56
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.<ExecuteRunAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
```

I am stuck at this for a long time now. I am a bit new to SF and don't know how to fix this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The exception says `DNS resolution failed for service: MININT-H7Q1KHO:50001`, therefore, you may want to check on the network side.

Comment: Thank you for your information but server instance is running properly. Is there any specific thing you want me to check as I can see the service up and running at the given address? @aybe

Comment: As pointed out above, clearly the problem is that gRPC is unable to the address. Things you can try: 1. use "grpcurl" https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl command line client to test the service is reachable manually 2. try setting GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native to use a different resolver (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out there is some problem with the gRPC library itself. The latest versions of the library show abnormal behaviour during DNS resolution on the service fabric cluster. However, this problem is mainly occurring with Windows only.

A workaround was to set the environment variable *"GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER=native"* somewhere early in the code. However, this is just a temporary fix and not recommended for production code.

A discussion thread regarding the same can be found here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18411